# how can i restrict a user to see only the slideshow and can't download it

Tags: php, cakephp, slideshow

i am developing a cake-php application, under this i want to show powerpoint slideshow for the end user but the condition is that the user can only be able to see the show, not be able to download the slideshow.
Can any one plz suggest the best way to do it.

Comment: In order to see it a user must download it in one form or fashion. Internet rule of thumb: If you don't want something to be downloaded, don't put it on the internet.

Comment: if user can view the pdf Then adobe acrobat reader automatically has hover on down-right the page to download. Mike's idea or you can just put the short brief of your pdf

Answer (score 1):

If the slideshow is based on images you can split each image into 9,16 or more squares and display the tiled image. That way if the user decides to 'Save-as' the image he will get only 1/9, or 1/16-th of the real image. If the slideshow is quite big it will be a pain to put together all the pieces and will discourage the users to try and save the slide.

You can see such implementation here - http://whatismycar.com/info/16540/ - the 4 images below the header are in fancybox and if you try to 'Save-as' one of them you will save only a small tile of the original image.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow that is a nice touch but what is stopping me from pressing `Ctrl+` a few times and then `Alt`+`PrtScn` followed by `Ctrl`+`V` into MS Paint? Yes, this idea will discourage simple users but if someone wants it then they will have it.

Comment: If somebody wants it he will find a way no matter what you do. However if you have to save a slideshow of 100+ pages using MSPaint it will be a pain even for a developer (some sites disable right mouse click but you can open your browser console and download the stuff from there). With this you might prefer just to find another source for your information :)

Comment: You are absolutely right. Na-zdorovya to hoping the user is not willing to perform a mundane task a few hundred times :)

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible prevent downloading images from internet, but you can make it hard for users with [this](http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/protect-online-photos.htm). Also you can hide source html image path with php check it [here](http://michael.theirwinfamily.net/articles/csshtml/protecting-images-using-php-and-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

While I am no expert on this subject, something worth noting is what Youtube seems to be doing.

Ever notice how the whole video never loads if you pause it?

Upon monitoring the network tab during a video you will see that they are actually making hundreds or even thousands of requests for video segments from their server and most likely using JS to clear the cache of parts you've watched.

^^ this is why going back to an earlier point in the video causes it to stall for a bit while it re-downloads the segment which you wish to see.

At the end of the day, `PrtScn` will trump all of your efforts because the web browser does not have the privilege to control the keyboard outside of it's own environment.